# Regex in PowerShell to get the city name from the Managedby property in Active Directory

Tags: regex, powershell

Can anyone help me with this. I need to derive a City name from the "managedby" attribute in Active Directory which looks like this:

```
CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com
```

So I need to take everything out and be left with `"PARIS"`

I really don't know enough about Regex but assume its going to involve using -replace in some way. I have tried following some examples on the web but I just get lost. I can remove all special characters using:

```
'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' -replace '[\W]', ''
```

But I have no idea how to clean that up further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need regex for that. If the structure of the distinguished name is always the same you can use nested `-split`s ... like this:

```
(('CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' -split '=')[3] -split ',')[0]
```

or this:

```
(('CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' -split ',')[-3] -split '=')[1]
```

I'd recommend the second version because this way you avoid confusion you can have with commas in the CN part of the distinguished name.  ;-)

If you like to do it with regex anyway you can use look-arounds to extract what's between the users OU and the domain like this:

```
'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' -match '(?<=Users,OU=).+(?=,DC=DOmain)'
$Matches[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)-based solution that assumes that the city name follows the *last* `,OU=` in the input string (though it wouldn't be hard to make the regex more specific).

It also supports city names with escaped `,` characters (`\,`), such as `PARIS\, Texas`.

```
$str = 'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS\, Texas,DC=Domain,DC=com' 
# -> 'PARIS, Texas'
$str -replace '.+,OU=(.+?),DC=.+', '$1' -replace '\\,', ','
```

- `.+,OU=` greedily matches one or more (`+`) arbitrary characters (`.`) up to the *last* `,OU=` substring in the input string.
- `(.+?)` matches on or more subsequent characters *non-greedily* (`+?`), via a capture group (capturing subexpression, `(...)`).
- `,DC=.+` matches the next occurrence of substring `,DC` followed by whatever is left in the string (`.+`).
- Note that this means that the regex matches the *entire* string, so that the value of the substitution expression, `$1`, is the only thing returned:

  - `$1` refers to the value of the 1st capture group, which contains the city name.
- The *second* `-replace` operation unescapes the `\,`, i.e. turns it into `,` - note how the literal `\` to replace had to be escaped as `\\` in the regex.

Comment: What if they had a seperate OU level for the state ... like this `'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,OU=Texas,DC=Domain,DC=com'`?  ;-) :-D